# User authentication from database

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Please help me fix the error in this program. The problem is, even if I use the correct username and password, I can't create a verified login.

```
public class LoginDao {
public static boolean CheckUser(String Username,String Password) 
 {
  boolean st =false;
  String dbUsername, dbPassword;

   try{


     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


     Connection con=DBConnection.getConnection();

        String qry ="select *user where Username=? and Password=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(qry);
     //pst.setString(1, Username);
     //pst.setString(2, Password);
     pst.executeQuery(qry);



        ResultSet rs = pst.getResultSet();

        while(rs.next()){
            dbUsername = rs.getString("Username");
            dbPassword = rs.getString("Password");

            if(dbUsername.equals(Username) && dbPassword.equals(Password)){
                System.out.println("Welcome");
                st = true;
            }

        }
   }

  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }



return st;

}
}
```

Comment: What error? Please be more specific.

Comment: Did you try to connect to the database without a verification or did you miss, to add the code snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Check your SQL query? You are missing a `FROM` before `*` and `user`. Also you need to set the parameters when using a `PreparedStatement`, you have them commented out.

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
public class LoginDao {
  public static boolean CheckUser(final String username, final String password) {
    final String qry ="SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username=? AND Password=?";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DBConnection.getConnection();
      pst = con.prepareStatement(qry);
      pst.setString(1, username);
      pst.setString(2, password);
      pst.executeQuery(qry);
      rs = pst.getResultSet();
      // Notice I changed the 'while' by 'if'
      if (rs.next()) {
        return (username.equals(rs.getString("Username")) && password.equals(rs.getString("Password")));
      }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // close/release (database resources) 'con', 'pst', 'rs' here
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```